# SQL Server (2016) Changing INT to BIGINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When changing an INT column to a BIGINT column on a table with over a 1 billion rows, is it still best practice to create a new table and then migrate the data, or is an `ALTER COLUMN` just as effective these days?

Not overly worried about downtime.

Comment: Why not race your horses in your dev environment? Though I would be surprised if recreating the table was more efficient; it's a much more expensive task.

Comment: I believe there is not much of a hit on resources since it is the same data type just bigger value.  If you were changing from 1 data type to another you would have bigger issues (ilke varchar to int or int to varchar for example).

Comment: If you have `DATA_COMPRESSION` then it's a metadata only operation, which will take milliseconds. https://am2.co/2019/12/changing-a-column-from-int-to-bigint-without-downtime/

Comment: i would probably add a new column with another name, copy data in batches and then drop original / renamed

Answer (score 4):

> is it still best practice to create a new table and then migrate the data,

That's just a workaround for running out of log space, or excessive blocking, or rollback time in case of failure.  So if you've got plenty of time and resources, just ALTER the table.

Just be aware that once you start the ALTER TABLE you're committed to let it finish or wait a possibly long time for it to roll back if you cancel it.

Bulk loading a new table can be aborted with little cost, as only the extent allocations need to be rolled back.